Time reference and conjunctions

When I cooked I watched Tv

I cooked and watched TV


1 implies two actions happened at the same time. What about 2? If we just numerate things it shows sequence or it is still possible that events happened at the same time?

The idiomatic way of expressing that idea is "I watched TV while I cooked" or "I cooked while I watched TV".

And can be ambiguous in some contexts. "What kind of sandwiches have you got?" "Roast beef and jam." (Meaning 'some of both kinds', but could be interpreted as all of them containing both fillings.)

Coordinated verbs entail nothing about sequence or about things happening at the same time. You could be responding to a question:

What did you do in Antarctica for nine months when you were working for that climate research project?
I cooked and watched TV.

There's no sense of one happening before or after the other, or at the same time. That's  just how you spent your time in Antarctica. It's what you did.
But sometimes, in practical contexts, the actions are understood to happen together:

Can you walk and chew gum?

However, that understanding is the result  the common saying: "We need to be able to walk and chew gum at the same time" and is not entailed by "and".

In the show she sings and dances.

Could be she does them together, but maybe she dances and after the dance she sings a song.
